# Timer en JavaScript o HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito un código de timer que cuando termine el tiempo me pase a otra pagina de HTML, es que estoy haciendo un proyecto que es como un examen entonces quiero que cuando termine me pase a la pagina de respuestas

Comment: Que llevas al momento? Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: ¿y crees que te vamos a hacer todo el código?

Answer (score 0):

```
const respCorrectas = document.querySelector('.page').innerHTML = new html
let evaluaRespuesta = setTimeout {
      respCorrectas,20000
  };
```

Comment: Da una breve explicacion para que se entienda

Answer (score -1):

Podrías utilizar:

```
window.onload = function() {
          setTimeout(redirect, 3000)
        }

        function redirect(){
        window.location="http:/google.com";
        }
```